# While training RasaNLU receiving the below error. "python -m rasa_core.train -d domain.yml -s stories.md -o models/dialogue"

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

error :

> Not all required packages are installed. To use this pipeline, you
>   need to install the missing dependencies. Please install Tensorflow

**Rasa NLU version**: 0.14.3

**Operating system** (windows, osx, ...): Windows 10

**Content of model configuration file**:

```
language: en
pipeline: tensorflow_embedding
```

**Issue**:

> File
>   "d:\prasanna\files\projects\github\nlu-chatbot\rasa_nlu\rasa_nlu\train.py",
>   line 133, in do_train trainer = Trainer(cfg, component_builder) File
>   "d:\prasanna\files\projects\github\nlu-chatbot\rasa_nlu\rasa_nlu\model.py",
>   line 141, in **init**
>   components.validate_requirements(cfg.component_names) File
>   "d:\prasanna\files\projects\github\nlu-chatbot\rasa_nlu\rasa_nlu\components.py",
>   line 47, in validate_requirements "Please install {}".format(",
>   ".join(failed_imports))) Exception: Not all required packages are
>   installed. To use this pipeline, you need to install the missing
>   dependencies. Please install tensorflow

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Comment: While training models for Rasa NLU i am receiving the error : Not all required packages are installed. To use this pipeline, you need to install the missing dependencies. Please install Tensorflow

Comment: I still don't see any question. What is your question? What you should do? Well, the error tells you - install tensorflow. Or don't you know how to install Tensorflow? Or do you have Tensorflow installed and think that the error message is wrong?

Comment: I have tried all those stuff. Still it shows like that so that only i have posted.

Comment: Then please, edit your post and add a correct question

Comment: In your question you should explain things like "What do you want to achieve?" "In what context are you getting the error?". The way your question is written, you probably won't be getting any help.

Comment: Can you help me on this @ibarrond ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install rasa nlu with included tensorflow as follows:

```
pip install rasa_nlu[tensorflow]
```

If you are using the NLU docker images, please use either the images with the `tensorflow` tag (e.g. `rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-tensorflow`) or the `full` images which include the dependencies for all pipelines (e.g. `rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-full`)